# Checkbox always "on" when sending to php

Tags: php, html

I have this checkbox in my html

```
<input name="cb" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
```

What I understood about how checkbox worked, was that when "checked" if you isset the input then it would "exist", and if wasn't "checked" wouldn't, so I did this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['cb'])){
   //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

The problem is that when sending the form, it always exist, doesn't matter if checked or not, I don't know how to really see if really checked, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your full html code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. So in your case, the `$_REQUEST['cb']` always exist, so `isset()` will be true. So if you have `isset()` in your condition, you need to add a check, if the value is true or false.

You need edit your condition to:

```
if($_REQUEST['cb']) { ...
```

or

```
if($_REQUEST['cb'] == true){ ...
```

and the best way is use isset with check above:

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['cb']) && $_REQUEST['cb'] == true ) { ...
```

Comment: @MiskateErorr I agree

Comment: be aware that if you use $_REQUEST['cb'] === true (strict comparison) it will result as false, because sent value is "on". unless you set value in your input

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['cb']) && $_REQUEST['cb']){
```